# How to set proxies like this "user:pass@6.6.6.6:8043" in FirefoxDriver of Selenium 2?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver

This is an example from selenium docs:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY_HOST = "host"
PROXY_PORT = 8080

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

# Direct = 0, Manual = 1, PAC = 2, AUTODETECT = 4, SYSTEM = 5
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)

fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", PROXY_PORT)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp", PROXY_HOST)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp_port", PROXY_PORT)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", PROXY_HOST)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", PROXY_PORT)

fp.set_preference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "") # set this value as desired

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

Well what if I want to set a private proxy such as `"user:pass@6.6.6.6:8043"`?

And another question, how do I catch http exceptions like 404, 403, 502, etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to pass a username and password like that.  How I would handle it is use webdriver to catch the popup and the send_keys() to that popup same as you would on a regular page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much into python, but I believe, that if you update these two values to:

```
PROXY_HOST = "user:pass@6.6.6.6"
PROXY_PORT = 8043
```

It should work.

BTW, on the same topic: I am also sitting behind the proxy and had never to set up proxy configuration in my firefox WebDriver.

I am using java, so it can be either the java WebDriver, or just the fact that I was accessing only the sites behind the proxy...

**EDIT**

try adding this into your profile. Hope it helps:

```
fp.setPreference("browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled", false);
```

above setting allows sending username and password in URL

Comment: Well, it doesn't work. You have to set it as `PROXY_HOST = "6.6.6.6"` and `PROXY_PORT = 8043`, then manually input user name and pass when authentication box pops up.

Comment: No I didn't solve it. I want a solution to automatically set proxy instead of manually input user/pass.

Comment: edited a little bit the answer. Hope it helps. If not, I am starting to be clueless

Comment: Are you sure it's working on your side? What language/platform do you use? Java + Selenium? I'm on Python + Selenium, and it does NOT work.

Comment: I am using the approach to log in to HTTP Auth protected sites, never tried it on proxy...

Answer (score 0):

After playing with Selenium for quite a while I came to realization that it's not designed for working with proxies, and it's definitely a pain in the ass If you are trying to make it work like what I did in the past. I eventually turned to tools like `requests` for most of my proxy related job.