# Selenium auto proxy username/password not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
ip = "username:password@123.456.78.9"
#ip = "http://username:password@123.456.78.9"  # tried this as well but same result

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", ip)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 80)
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override","some_user_agent")
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://www.whatismyip.com/')
```

when I do this page doesn't load(as internet is disconnected) but when I remove username:password thing from `ip` variable a window popup asks for username password.

I dont know how to automate this thing I mean pass username/pass programatically?
I dont even know how to pass username/pass in popup (how do I use `send_keys` when I dont know the tag name)
I did `alert = driver.switch_to.alert`  now what?

anyway would be great if  there is some thing like

```
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.user_name", 'username')
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.password", 'password')
```

and I'm not aware of.

I've already visited 5-6 SOF threads and tried their solution(all of them are suggesting same solution but in 2012/13).
here [How to set proxies like this "user:pass@6.6.6.6:8043" in FirefoxDriver of Selenium 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499754/how-to-set-proxies-like-this-userpass6-6-6-68043-in-firefoxdriver-of-seleni)
somebody posted(in 2012) a solution in Java
do we have similar thing `fp.setPreference("browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled", false);`
in python?